# Support for iOS10 "mutable-content" flag in Parse Push Notification

Tags: swift, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I am currently trying to implement the new rich notification feature in iOS10. To do so I need to be able to send a `mutable-content` flag through the APNS. Below is the data property embedded in the a curl.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: qwdfwrkwergjpowefjrgowerjhoiwjehojwerw" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: asdfasdfasdfasdfasderhwerhretjadsfwrthw" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "className":"_User",
    "where":{
      "user":{
        "__type":"Pointer",
        "className":"_User",
        "objectId":"O7zXzrEc8z"
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "alert": " Testing push notications",
      "product":"510958372",
      "mutable-content": 1,
      "content-available": 1,
      "category":"product-share"
    }
  }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

I can see that `content-available` flag is being passed but `mutable-content` is not.

```
trigger: <UNPushNotificationTrigger: 0x175a12930; contentAvailable: YES, mutableContent: NO>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some follow up.

Parse.com does not currently support these new iOS features but Parse Server does. There's currently other services that can be integrated that are currently configured for iOS10 new features right now. One for example is OneSignal which I've just successfully implemented.